# How to make a push button animation?

Tags: java, android, onclick, android-animation

i was thinking to animate a button , i want to simulate a big push button like [this](http://make-everything-ok.com/) one

i have the image of the button , i want to animate the press down animation and the shadow effect

i have done the push down animation with this

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_click_anim);

public void onClick(View v){ v.startAnimation(animation);}
```

and in the `anim` directory i have button_click_anim

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9"
        android:duration="100"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:duration="100"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
```